# How would I extract a variable length piece of text from a string using PHP?

Tags: php, string

I am going to read in via XML a string of text that gives a time in minutes and seconds as below:

"79 minutes 43 seconds"

But I need to extract the minutes.

The minutes could be a 1,2,3 or 4 figure number with the word "minutes" after a space, then the seconds which I am not interested in.

How could I extract the minutes figure into a separate string using PHP?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `(int)` cast to convert any leading digits of a string into a number:

```
$minutes = (int)"79 minutes 43 seconds";
```

This approach is limited to strings that start with a number and this number always means minutes. For other cases, it's probably better to use regular expressions.

Answer (score 1):

If there might be other text in front of the minutes number, you can extract the value using a regex:

```
$matches = array();
preg_match("/(\d+) minutes/", $your_input, $matches);
$num_minutes = (int)$matches[1];
```

Comment: You're correct about the missing delimiter, but you're wrong about the escape - the `"\\d"` translates into a `\d` string, because the `\\` is a single slash after *PHP's* string escaping. The PHP regex engine is smart enough to *also* accept the control character generated by `"\d"` alone, but will happily accept `"\\d"` as well (try it). If you want to match a literal slash, you actually have to use `"\\\\"` to first get around PHP's string escaping and then the regex engine's escaping.